# private to public domain redirecting in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have two apache webservers, one public and one private. The requirement is that the users will access the **PUBLIC** domain and get the content from the **PRIVATE** domain. The **PUBLIC** domain should be empty and contain only the .htaccess file used for users authentication.
All the requests will come to `http://public.com:60001/` and get rewritten by apache to `http://private:60001/`. Users cannot access **PRIVATE** domain directly, but the server where **PUBLIC** domain is hosted has connection to it.

To achive this, I updated the virtual host of the **PUBLIC** domain to include this:

```
<Directory "/wwwroot/public.com">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://private:60001/$1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse http://private:60001/
</Directory>
```

After doing this, the pages are loading but with two issues:

1. All the links in html code of the pages of the website will be in the form of `http://private:60001/` so when the user is clicking on the links they get a 404 error (since they don't have connection to that). Is there a way for apache to rewrite those links to `http://public.com:60001/`?
2. Ajax calls don't work - a 404 error is generated. I think that maybe is because of the same issue as at point 1.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod_proxy isn't going to fix your problem. You're going to need to remove all the hostnames from your content from **private**. So instead of having links like:

```
<a href="http://private:60001/something/">
```

They need to look like:

```
<a href="/something/">
```

Otherwise you can look into [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html), which will actually mangle the page's content (as opposed to just the request) and map the links in the content on private so that they link to public. See [this link](http://ckdake.com/node/235) for some examples.

Essentially, something along the lines of:

```
ProxyHTMLLogVerbose On
ProxyHTMLLinks  a               href
ProxyHTMLLinks  link            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  form            action
ProxyHTMLLinks  script          src for
ProxyHTMLLinks  img             src longdesc usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  iframe          src

ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
            onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
            onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
            onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

ProxyHTMLURLMap url\(http://private:60001([^\)]*)\) url(http://public:60001$1) Rihe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not aware of mod_proxy_html.